# How does SSL work on two connected domains?

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate

I've read through related questions but couldn't quite find what I am looking for.
I have set up a domain just as "domain.com" and created two subdomains "client.domain.com" and "client-intern.domain.com". Further, there is a redirect active for "client.domain.com/intern" pointing to "client-intern.domain.com".

If I buy a single SSL certificate for "client.domain.com", will the data transfer also be secured when the client is going to "client.domain.com/intern"?
Or do I have to purchase a second certificate for "client-intern.domain.com"?

Thanks in advance for clarification,
Paul

UPDATE: If entering "client.domain.com/intern" into the web browsers address bar, this address remains there and the browser shows the content of "client-intern.domain.com" nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a wildcard certificate to cover multiple subdomains (in your case domain.com, client.domain.com and client-intern.domain.com). Some CAs might offer you an option to include one or two subdomains into the certificate (as alternative name field) for free or for a small additional fee, but this is CA-dependent and in general the right way is a wildcard certificate. You can read about wildcard certs [here (GlobalSign site)](http://www.globalsign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/wildcard-ssl/).

Comment: I didn't mention that explicitly but I am well aware of wildcard SSL certificates. Since these are quite expensive (opposed to just buy one or two single domain SSL certificates) and since I only want to protect these two subdomains I posted this question.
The main questions is whether I need two certificates or or if I'd be fine with one SSL certificate for "client.domain.com"?

Comment: If the browser connects to client-intern.domain.com (i.e. resolves this address), then you need a domain for it. If "redirection" is done by creating an alias in the server, then you don't need a domain for it. But it seems that in any of those cases your question is better suitable for http://serverfault.com